# Hide every instance of an input field but the first one

Tags: jquery, css

I have a form, on the first page of the form the user can select how many people to register, in the next step the form asks the same questions for each registrant. I would like for one of the questions to only display for the first registrant and be hidden for the other registrants.

Each of the div's use practically the same naming but the number after rptAttributesPerRegistrant changes, I want to show

```
#PC4187_ev2wiz_step2_ctlRegs_rptPerEvent_ctlAttributes_0_rptRegistrants_0_rptAttributesPerRegistrant_0_lblAttributeName_0
```

but hide any others, for example, hide the following:

```
#PC4187_ev2wiz_step2_ctlRegs_rptPerEvent_ctlAttributes_0_rptRegistrants_0_rptAttributesPerRegistrant_1_lblAttributeName_0
#PC4187_ev2wiz_step2_ctlRegs_rptPerEvent_ctlAttributes_0_rptRegistrants_0_rptAttributesPerRegistrant_2_lblAttributeName_0
```

and so on . . .

Please see for the entire code http://jsfiddle.net/jelane20/U6kja/

I do not want to hide the vegetarian field however which also uses the same type of div

I am not sure how to target every instance of the div but the first one and exclude the vegetarian question, I need to hide any of the divs that use a number greater than 0. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: These are awful ID selectors, really. Sorry i know it doesn't help you much

Comment: Those look like asp.net ids, auto-generated and not really meant to be read by a human. I would give your elements a common class, at which point selecting all but the first becomes trivial.

Comment: Like this http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/U6kja/2/?

Comment: In CSS input:not([value="0"]) {display:none;}, i believe jQuery as the same selector that you can use.https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/ CSS ex: http://jsfiddle.net/U6kja/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see the below fiddle
[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sb_satchitanand/U6kja/4/)

Whenever you have long value for attributes and want to match a particular part you have use jquery [attribute selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

```
$("[id*='rptAttributesPerRegistrant']")
```

The above statement will give you all the selectors containing "rptAttributesPerRegistrant"
then you can filter out based on type etc.

Comment: why a down vote? Down voter can you please justify it?

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear to me what you're trying to accomplish, but this shows only the first registrant options:

```
$('div.Ev2_AttributeContent').children().not(':first-child').hide();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Q82TT/

To show the options for the second registrant:

```
$('div.Ev2_AttributeContent').children().not(':nth-child(3)').hide();
```

... and for the third:

```
$('div.Ev2_AttributeContent').children().not(':nth-child(5)').hide();
```

Comment: The user is able to add more than 3 registrants, so say if they register 4 people, then there will be 4 instances of the question *Family you'd like to sit with (if possible), I need to hide all of these but the first one, no matter how many registrants they add, so it needs to be more dynamic then using nth-child